# Fast integration of 2D marginal likelihoods

Tags: bayesian, numerical-integration

I need to compute a large number of integrals of the form:
$$
\mathcal{I}(\Theta) = p(x_1,x_2|\theta) = \int p(x_1,x_2|y_1,y_2,\theta) p(y_1,y_2|\theta) dy_1 dy_2
$$

with $x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2 \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\theta$ is a parameter vector, and $\Theta \equiv (x_1, x_2, \theta)$.

The integral is non-analytical, but being 2D I could easily evaluate each one numerically (e.g., via trapezoidal rule). The problem is that I need to perform this computation for a *large* number of $\Theta$, and I want it to be as fast and precise as possible.

Note that:

- For a given $\Theta$, I can compute an analytical coarse estimate of the location and spread of the integrand (via a normal approximation).
- As far as I have seen, the integrand is unimodal and looks like a "skewed bivariate normal", sometimes with quite long tails. A Laplace approximation would *not* be great.
- Any computation needs to be vectorizable (e.g., in MATLAB), as I will perform it in parallel on a massive number of $\Theta$.

Any suggestion?

The best idea I have had so far is to estimate location/spread of each integral and simply use trapezoidal integration on a local $\Theta$-dependent grid.

Comment: PS: I am not *entirely* sure that this question is perfect for CrossValidated as it is mostly about numerical methods (although applied to a fairly common statistical problem). I am okay if the moderators decide to move it to some other site.

Comment: can you sample from $p(y_1,y_2|\theta)$ ?

Comment: Yes, I can. I hope you're not suggesting to sample from $p(y_1,y_2|\theta)$?

Comment: I was suggesting Monte Carlo integration but it looks that you are not interested in ... It can be paralelized and the variance of the estimator reduces arbitrarly low with the dedicated computation time. Interested ?

Comment: (+1) Thanks! I'd be interested in effective methods, but sampling from $p(y_1, y_2 | \theta)$ is rarely effective. Like many marginal likelihoods, the integral is going to be defined in a narrow region and sampling from the prior will have a *huge* variance (a related approach has been called in the literature the "worst Monte Carlo method ever"). I have a way to roughly find out where the integral is defined, and I could sample in that region, but I don't see why MC would be better than numerical integration in 2D (the rule of thumb is that MC integration becomes convenient for $D \ge 4$).